# how to use previous stored value in iterator in scala?

Tags: scala

I have

```
var a = List (1,2,3,4,5)

a.map( e => if(e%2==0) (e*2) else (**))
```

** =At this place I want to only use value which are already updated

How can I do this?

Comment: What should happen at ** when you do not yet have an already-updated value?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I assume (4,2,7) should become (4,2,2) is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```scala
val a = List(1,2,3,4)

val r = a.foldLeft(List[Int]()){
  (l, e) => if(e % 2 == 0) e :: l else (l.fold(0)(math.max(_, _))) :: l
}.reverse
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. but i have updated the question.